# In React components, where to store unchanging data returned from api so that component methods can have access to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My understanding of state variables in React is that only data that changes as a result of user interaction or asynchronous data flow should be stored in state. What if I need to request list data from several APIs and then combine these to make a new master list to serve as a constant source of truth that may need to be used by various component methods during phases of user interaction? What is the correct place to store unchanging data like this? It's tempting to put this data in state for easy access but that doesn't seem right. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Redux or Mobx for this scenario. and if you don't know anyone you can try to put it in the local storage if that data is not confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use redux, in this case. It's OK to save your API data call to state, even though the data won't change. If you don't want to save it to state you can save it to a static or global variable.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   API_DATA = []; // save data here

   state = {
     api_data: [] // it's ok too
   }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // call to api
    // save data to API_DATA
    this.API_DATA = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: The above suggestions had crossed my mind before and they do seem rational to me.

Comment: The only thing is that if you need other component methods to use API_DATA then they won't be purely functional since they're not taking API_DATA directly as an input. That was another issue I was wondering about. Maybe you can't have everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is where something like React hooks or Redux would come in handy. If you're unfamiliar, both can be used to globally store state. Redux would be better for high frequency changes but it sounds like hooks would be best for your situation.

There are plenty of tutorials out there for this on Youtube, the React subreddit, etc.